# Is it possible for ISPs to block part of VPN traffic, like UDP traffic only

Tags: vpn, voip, isp, telephony

My Question isn't about any carrier or ISP, as it might sound.
It's about the technical aspect of internet censorship and needs networking experts to help.
As you may know, some countries are blocking access to whatsapp calls, but users usually overcome that with a VPN service, but today even with that powerful internet anonymity solution, ISPs and telecom operators are blocking whatsapp calls even when using VPN on your phone. The question is, how are ISPs able to detect that traffic, as it's encrypted, and ban such voip services. Any technical details would be great, thank you experts.

Comment: Have you tried any other VPN providers? It may be that the current VPN provider you are using has been blacklisted/blocked

Comment: Your ISP's policies are off-topic here. What business arrangement you have with your ISP is between you two.

Comment: Well, my question isn't about the ISP nor the contract, it's deeply technical, it's about the ability to analyse the encrypted VPN traffic by ISPs or any other parties.

Comment: Yes, SleepyMan, we have tried many providers, but it seems that it's whatsapp who's blocking the calls from specific countries besides ISPs.

Comment: Neither is Internet censorship on-topic here. As it says, "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._" Also off-topic are "_a network under someone else's control_" and "_bypassing network security or policies_."

Comment: So if I put my question in a business context that would make it on-topic.

Comment: Only if it is your network, and you are not trying to bypass network security or _policies_ on someone else's network, e.g. the ISP's network.

Answer (score 1):

There three main types of censorship: 
1. Internet Protocol (IP) address blocking or AS blocking
2. TLD's blocking
3. ISP filtring

Although VPN traffic is encapsulated and content invisible for ISP. And there isn't possible to censorship/filter traffic. Some countries may block edge IP address of various VPN providers. The issue could be that phone doesn't send all traffic thru VPN provider and this traffic is filtered.